# Windows 10 ssh not working with correct password

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I followed the instructions to install OpenSSH on Windows 10, but I am not able to ssh with the correct password, even from the local machine where ssh server is running. Just to be sure I am using the correct password, I created a new account but it doesn't work. It also doesn't work from a remote machine.

Update: I installed an alternative SSH server (bitvise). Initially, it also didn't allow me to connect but gave the helpful error that - "Windows accounts aren't allowed to connect". Once I enabled that, I was able to connect with bitvise.

How can I enable the same setting in OpenSSH?

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Ashok\.ssh> ssh -vvv bunkoo@localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'bunkoo'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qYW2HlanEuzgBhNA0prksdosut07EjFLnuEEAeP/l0A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ashok/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
bunkoo@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
bunkoo@localhost's password:
```

Comment: Which instructions? There at least three or four ways to install different OpenSSH builds on Windows (the built-in Win10 feature; the Microsoft GitHub site; Cygwin).

Comment: I used the instructions from here 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting in OpenSSH, because there are no *virtual accounts* in OpenSSH – native OS accounts (i.e. Windows accounts) are already the only kind it supports.

You should search the OpenSSH **server** log entries (eventvwr.msc → *Apps and Services* → *OpenSSH* → *Operational*) to determine why it is rejecting your login.

```
Get-WinEvent OpenSSH/Operational -Oldest | ft Message
```

```
wevtutil qe OpenSSH/Operational /f:Text
```

If the normal messages don't reveal anything odd, then edit the file `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` to add `LogLevel VERBOSE` or even `LogLevel DEBUG3`, then restart the OpenSSH Server service and you should be getting far more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you. After struggling for days, your message finally helped me resolve this issue. It was failing because the PowerShell wasn't configured.